# WebSocket Java Spring Boot Authentication with JWT

Tags: spring, security, websocket, jwt, spring-websocket

I am trying to build a chat web application. When the user sends a new message (HTTP Request) to the server, I want to send WebSocket notification to the receiver of the message (Angular Client). When the user logs in to the app it opens a websocket connection with the server. I would like to ask you if my logic is right or I can do something better. I want to intercept the handshake before it gets established and grab the session id of the websocket and the Session JWT cookie of the user, so I can store them in my database. So when a user sends a message, the backend should lookup database if there is active websocket connection or not. ALthough, I find this solution difficult to build as I am not sure a websocket session ID is enough to rebuild the Websocket session object from the start. Is there any better way to solve this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/q/75650473/175554