# Spring boot 3 websockets not authenticating with JWT

Tags: angular, spring-boot, websocket, jwt

I have a spring boot 3 app and I have implemented jwt authentication for the http requests,
I now need to use webosckets but because I cannot add the Bearer token to the websocket the websocket is failing. I can connect to the websocket from postman when I add to the header the bearer. but I cannot connect from the angular.

I have tried adding the token to the websocket url as a query parameter in angular:

```
    this.socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:9090/my-websocket-endpoint?token=' + localStorage.getItem("jwt"));
```

and I have implmented the doFilterInternal this way:

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
  Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JwtAuthenticationFilter.class);

  private final JwtService jwtService;
  private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
  private final TokenRepository tokenRepository;

  @Override
  protected void doFilterInternal(
      @NonNull HttpServletRequest request,
      @NonNull HttpServletResponse response,
      @NonNull FilterChain filterChain
  ) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String query = request.getQueryString();
    boolean jwtInQuery = false;
    if (query != null && query.startsWith("token")) {
      System.out.println("Token: " + query.substring(7));
      jwtInQuery = true;
    }
    final String authHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
    final String jwt;
    final String userEmail;
    if ((authHeader == null ||!authHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) && !jwtInQuery) {
      filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
      return;
    }
    if (jwtInQuery) {
      jwt = query.substring(7);
    } else {
      jwt = authHeader.substring(7);
    }
    userEmail = jwtService.extractUsername(jwt);
    if (userEmail != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
      UserDetails userDetails = this.userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(userEmail);
      var isTokenValid = tokenRepository.findByToken(jwt)
          .map(t -> !t.isExpired() && !t.isRevoked())
          .orElse(false);
      if (jwtService.isTokenValid(jwt, userDetails) && isTokenValid) {
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
            userDetails,
            null,
            userDetails.getAuthorities()
        );
        authToken.setDetails(
            new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request)
        );
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authToken);
      }
    }
    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
  }
}
```

and the securityFilterChain

```
package com.threatsoft.vulnslayer.config;

import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutHandler;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.EnableWebSocket;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EnableWebSocket
public class SecurityConfiguration {

  private final JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthFilter;
  private final AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;
  private final LogoutHandler logoutHandler;

  @Bean
  public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .csrf()
        .disable()
        .authorizeHttpRequests()
        .requestMatchers("/login")
          .permitAll()
        .anyRequest()
          .authenticated()
        .and()
          .sessionManagement()
          .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and()
        .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
        .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
        .logout()
        .logoutUrl("/api/v1/auth/logout")
        .addLogoutHandler(logoutHandler)
        .logoutSuccessHandler((request, response, authentication) -> SecurityContextHolder.clearContext());

    return http.build();
  }
}
```

I can see the token from the request going through the doFilterInternal but it does nt authenticate, What I am looking for is a way to either exclude websockets from the authentication and do custom authentication after the handshake, or a way to authenticate them using the existing filters.

any pointers to examples or tutorial would be highly appreciated.